# How do I sort a JSON by Date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I'm trying to loop through a JSON and sort it by the date so I can see the latest date to the oldest date, and then write it to the file.

Here is my code

```
var reader = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('txt.json', 'utf8'));
function sortByDate(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.lastUpdated).toJSON() - new Date(b.lastUpdated).toJSON();
}

reader.sort(sortByDate)
```

JSON Data Example

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Contents": [
            {
                "Key": [
                    "HelloTest"
                ],
                "lastUpdated": [
                    "2019-10-25T10:30:50.558Z"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Key": [
                    "TestHello"
                ],
                "lastUpdated": [
                    "2019-03-26T10:30:50.558Z"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `Key` and `lastUpdated` are collections in your json so I think you should try `a.lastUpdated[0]` and `b.lastUpdated[0]`

Comment: TypeError: reader.sort is not a function, that's the error I'm getting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-by-property

Comment: Can you update the question with your latest code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of errors I found in your code:

- Your function name has a typo, it should be `sortByDate` and not `sortbyDate`.
- You need top sort the inner json.Data.Contents array, not the outer json object.
- You need to reference the first element of your `lastUpdated` arrays using `lastUpdated[0]`.
- Finally, you do not need to call `toJSON()` on the date objects in your sorting function, simply convert to date and return the difference.

Also your inner data fields are arrays, which seems strange for a `Key` and a `lastUpdated` value.

If you keep your fields as arrays, here is a working example showing how to sort the inner `Data.Contents` array by date:

```js
const jsonString = `{
  "Data": {
    "Contents": [{
        "Key": ["HelloTest"],
        "lastUpdated": ["2019-10-25T10:30:50.558Z"]
      }, {
        "Key": ["TestHello"],
        "lastUpdated": ["2019-03-26T10:30:50.558Z"]
      }]
  }
}`;

function sortByDate(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.lastUpdated[0]) - new Date(b.lastUpdated[0]);
}

const json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
const defaultValue = { Data: { Contents: [] } };
const sortedContents = [...(json || defaultValue).Data.Contents].sort(sortByDate);
const output = { ...json, Data: { Contents: sortedContents } };

console.log(output);
```

If you change your fields to scalars, which I suggest, here is another example:

```js
const jsonString = `{
  "Data": {
    "Contents": [{
        "Key": "HelloTest",
        "lastUpdated": "2019-10-25T10:30:50.558Z"
      }, {
        "Key": "TestHello",
        "lastUpdated": "2019-03-26T10:30:50.558Z"
      }]
  }
}`;

function sortByDate(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.lastUpdated) - new Date(b.lastUpdated);
}

const json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
const defaultValue = { Data: { Contents: [] } };
const sortedContents = [...(json || defaultValue).Data.Contents].sort(sortByDate);
const output = { ...json, Data: { Contents: sortedContents } };

console.log(output);
```

Comment: **Perfect!** I'm using an old XML file that I had to convert to a JSON by making a function, thanks for the help I understand the errors I have made now.

Comment: Cleaner than converting to a date is to just test `a.lastUpdated < b.lastUpdated ? -1 : a.lastUpdated > b.lastUpdated ? 1 : 0`.  No reason to do all those `Date` conversions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reading contents from a file, then needs to sort it by date, and then finally write it to a new file. If that is what you're going for, the following should help:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// JSON files can be requied in as objects without parsing
// `arrayOfStuff` will be the var name for `Contents`
const { Data: { Contents: arrayOfStuff } } = require('./data.json');

function sortByDate(el1, el2) {
  // access the date from the object and turn into date object
  let date1 = new Date(el1.lastUpdated[0]);
  let date2 = new Date(el2.lastUpdated[0]);
  // compare date objects in revers order to get newest to oldest
  return (date2 - date1);
}

// sort `Contents` from the `Data` object and turn into JSON
const sortedContent = arrayOfStuff.sort(sortByDate);
const newDataObj = JSON.stringify({ Data: { Content: sortedContent }}, null, 2);

// create the fully qualified file path with `sortedByDate.json` as the file name
const filePath = path.resolve('./', 'sortedByDate.json');

// write to new file
fs.writeFile(filePath, newDataObj, (err) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Made an oopsie:', err);
  }
    console.log(`Success!, new JSON file located at: ${filePath}`);
}); // write to file
```

Comment: Ok I've tried this however my JSON is called images.json and it's returning `can't find module ./images.json`

Comment: You would normally get that error message when the file path is incorrect. I would double-check where the `images.json` is located from the relative file from where your script is running.